# How to disable search button after first click until results come from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

```html
<form action="action_page.php">
  Search Google:
  <input type="search" name="googlesearch">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I enter something into input field for the first time and then click on search button it should be disabled but until the related results come and it should be enabled again. Or other option is that after first search-click the input field should become empty or clear after related results come and I can make the button enabled again when I will focus for the input field for the second time for second time search.

Comment: How you are fetching results? AJAX ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it can be done. First remove `action="action_page.php"` from `form` tag because it will call form submit method which we don't want.

When search button is clicked we will disable it until we will get response from server.

Here is a prototype code.

```
$('#submit-btn').click(function(){
 $('#submit-btn').attr('disabled',true); // Disable button
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST'
   url: 'action_page.php',
   data: {
      searchWords:$('search-inp').val()
   },
   success: function(data) { // After Success
        doSomethingWithData(data);
        $('#submit-btn').attr('disabled',false); // Enable button
   },
 });
});
```

Comment: You don't actually have to remove `action="action_page.php"`, nonetheless if you do so, but keep an `input` with `type=submit` the form will still submit...

Comment: Was confused between these two.So i have never used them when making an AJAX call.

Comment: you can keep both, the action attribute and the `input type=submit` if you use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) in your jQuery function

Comment: @webeno Thank you. i will try this from next time :-).

Comment: Hi all I want one more help.

Comment: I want to do the same thing for enter button simultaneously with click

Answer (score 1):

Try preventing the default behaviour of the form by using `event.preventDefault()`, add the relevant code you like it to do, then ensure a callback is added to your result fetching function that makes the button enabled again when it's done (this will depend on how you're doing this exactly).

The bit that takes care of the preventing could look something like this (merged with your original code):

```js
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    // do your form posting, then add in its 'success' function the following:
    // $(the_original_submit_button).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="action_page.php">
  Search Google:
  <input type="search" name="googlesearch">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Note: the `the_original_submit_button` selector has been explicitly named so, as if you're using it inside another function that takes care of the form posting (like AJAX for example), the selector for the submit button may not be `this` (it will probably become the object of the AJAX call, again, assuming you're using AJAX), so you're going to have to pass it inside your function somehow, eg. by defining it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ajax, you could set onsubmit event with 
    return false while ajax readyState<4